# MS Access 13 SQL: How can I combine the results of four aggregate count subqueries?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

Essentially, I am trying to get a count of all employees that are within 1 month, 2 months, 3 months and past certain safety course expiry dates. All four queries are pulling data from the same set of tables.

So far, I have created one query that does this for one condition and duplicated it for each date range. The data set returned is similar to the following:

```
Company | EX |
--------------
Acme    | 27 |
Bacme   | 87 |
EBDC    | 21 |
...
```

What I am trying to do now is combine them so that I have a query that returns a data set like the following.

```
Company | EX | M1 | M2 | M3 |
-----------------------------
Acme    | 27 | 32 | 76 | 40 |
Bacme   | 87 | 12 | 33 | 76 |
EBDC    | 21 | 44 | 65 | 87 |
```

I have tried creating a union but did not get the result I wanted and I have also been trying to create an inner join in a sub query.

But, don't really know what I'm doing. I'd be grateful for any help in solving this problem thanks!

After the below advice I was able to construct this uber query! And it works just fine.

```
<pre>
SELECT 
   Q0.CN, 
   Q0.EX, 
   Q1.M1, 
   Q2.M2, 
   Q3.M3
FROM 
   (((((
   SELECT 
      Companies.[Company Name] AS [CN], 
      Count(Companies.[Company Name]) AS [EX]
   FROM 
      (SELECT 
         Companies.[Company Name] 
      FROM 
         Courses INNER JOIN 
         ((Companies INNER JOIN 
           Candidates ON 
           Companies.[ID] = Candidates.[Company ID]) INNER JOIN 
           [Individual Candidate Course History] ON 
           Candidates.[ID] = [Individual Candidate Course History].[Candidate ID]) ON 
           Courses.[ID] = [Individual Candidate Course History].[Course ID] 
    WHERE 
       (([Individual Candidate Course History].[Valid Until])<Date()) 
    ORDER BY 
       [Individual Candidate Course History].[Valid Until]) 
    GROUP BY 
       Companies.[Company Name]) AS Q0 LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
       Companies.[Company Name] AS [CN], 
       Count(Companies.[Company Name]) AS M1
     FROM 
        (SELECT 
           Companies.[Company Name] 
         FROM 
           Courses INNER JOIN 
           ((Companies INNER JOIN 
             Candidates ON 
             Companies.[ID] = Candidates.[Company ID]) INNER JOIN 
             [Individual Candidate Course History] ON 
             Candidates.[ID] = [Individual Candidate Course History].[Candidate ID]) ON 
             Courses.[ID] = [Individual Candidate Course History].[Course ID] 
    WHERE 
       ((([Individual Candidate Course History].[Valid Until]) 
       Between Date() And DateAdd("m",1,Date()))) 
    ORDER BY 
       [Individual Candidate Course History].[Valid Until]) 
    GROUP BY 
       Companies.[Company Name]) AS Q1 ON 
   Q0.CN = Q1.CN) LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT 
      Companies.[Company Name] AS [CN], 
      Count(Companies.[Company Name]) AS M2
    FROM 
       (SELECT 
          Companies.[Company Name] 
        FROM 
          Courses INNER JOIN 
          ((Companies INNER JOIN 
          Candidates ON 
          Companies.[ID] = Candidates.[Company ID]) INNER JOIN 
          [Individual Candidate Course History] ON 
          Candidates.[ID] = [Individual Candidate Course History].[Candidate ID]) ON 
          Courses.[ID] = [Individual Candidate Course History].[Course ID] 
       WHERE 
          ((([Individual Candidate Course History].[Valid Until]) 
         Between DateAdd("m",1,Date()) And DateAdd("m",2,Date()))) 
      ORDER BY 
         [Individual Candidate Course History].[Valid Until]) 
 GROUP BY 
    Companies.[Company Name] 
 ORDER BY 
    Companies.[Company Name]) AS Q2 ON 
 Q0.CN = Q2.CN) LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT 
    Companies.[Company Name] AS [CN], 
    Count(Companies.[Company Name]) AS M3
  FROM 
    (SELECT 
       Companies.[Company Name] 
    FROM 
       Courses INNER JOIN 
       ((Companies INNER JOIN 
       Candidates ON 
       Companies.[ID] = Candidates.[Company ID]) 
       INNER JOIN [Individual Candidate Course History] ON 
       Candidates.[ID] = [Individual Candidate Course History].[Candidate ID]) ON 
       Courses.[ID] = [Individual Candidate Course History].[Course ID] 
    WHERE 
    ((([Individual Candidate Course History].[Valid Until]) 
    Between DateAdd("m",2,Date()) And DateAdd("m",3,Date()))) 
    ORDER BY 
       [Individual Candidate Course History].[Valid Until]) 
    GROUP BY 
       Companies.[Company Name] 
 ORDER BY 
    Companies.[Company Name]) AS Q3 ON 
 Q0.CN = Q3.CN))
        </pre>
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show the query that you have constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using only one query with conditional aggregates for month columns. While I do not know your date expression, move each query's `WHERE` clause into an `IIF()` logic statement wrapped in `SUM()` of 1's and 0's calculation. Also, adjust `FROM` clause with any needed `JOIN` statements.

```
SELECT t.Company, Count(t.*) AS [EX],
       SUM(IIF(DATEDIFF('m', Date(), t.ExpiryDate) = 1, 1, 0) AS [M1],
       SUM(IIF(DATEDIFF('m', Date(), t.ExpiryDate) = 2, 1, 0) AS [M2],
       SUM(IIF(DATEDIFF('m', Date(), t.ExpiryDate) = 3, 1, 0) AS [M3]
FROM TableName t
GROUP BY t.Company
```

Per OP's update of actual working query, consider the following query using no subqueries:

```
SELECT 
   Companies.[Company Name] AS [CN], 
   SUM(IIF([Individual Candidate Course History].[Valid Until] <= Date(), 1, 0)) AS [EX],
   SUM(IIF([Individual Candidate Course History].[Valid Until]
           BETWEEN Date() AND DateAdd("m",1,Date()), 1, 0)) AS [M1],
   SUM(IIF([Individual Candidate Course History].[Valid Until]
           BETWEEN DateAdd("m",1,Date()) AND DateAdd("m",2,Date()), 1, 0)) AS [M2],
   SUM(IIF([Individual Candidate Course History].[Valid Until]
           BETWEEN DateAdd("m",2,Date()) AND DateAdd("m",3,Date()), 1, 0)) AS [M3]

FROM       
   Courses INNER JOIN 
   ((Companies INNER JOIN 
     Candidates ON Companies.[ID] = Candidates.[Company ID]) 
     INNER JOIN [Individual Candidate Course History] 
         ON Candidates.[ID] = [Individual Candidate Course History].[Candidate ID]) 
   ON Courses.[ID] = [Individual Candidate Course History].[Course ID]  
GROUP BY 
   Companies.[Company Name]
```

Comment: Just used the above works fine, thank you Parfait! And now i've turned it into a SELECT ... INTO statement!!!

Comment: Fantastic! Please accept the most helpful answer to confirm resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You want `Left join`

```
select Qry1.Company, Qry1.Ex, Qry2.Ex as M1, Qry3.Ex as M2, Qry4.Ex as M3
from ((Qry1
left join Qry2
  on Qry1.Company = Qry2.Company)
left join Qry3
  on Qry1.Company = Qry3.Company)
left join Qry4
  on Qry1.Company = Qry4.Company
```

Comment: Do note in MS Access SQL join pairings require parentheses, else OP will hit an error.

Comment: I still don't understand why Access doesn't operate with SQL Server syntax... Stupid MS.

Comment: Parentheses are not required around `ON` clauses but `JOIN` statements. See my edit.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks, it's been a while

Comment: This one seems to be working with 2 queries. Gonna keep adding them. Thanks John!

Comment: Yep, av done now! It's like playing pass the parcel, but in reverse and with parenthesis! Thank you :-)

Comment: OP - please reconsider your query for both efficiency, readability, and maintainability. Since all subqueries are same structure except `WHERE` clause, use conditional aggregation as I show.